# Simplification of Boolean expression for logic

Tags: logic, computer-science, boolean-logic

```
-
A
```

is equivalent to negative A (which is -A) then for,

```
-----------
 -   -   -
(A + B + C)
```

Is it A + B + C? or is it ABC?

Thanks!

Comment: Draw a table that covers all the options of binary values of A, B and C, then for each such combination check the values of both expressions, if they're exactly the same in all cases it means they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

It is equal to **A V B V C** ("V" for OR) because when the expression would be False => when this expression will be True:

```
 -   -   -
(A + B + C)
```

And this one would be Only When all A, B, C would be False.
So it will be false only when all variables will be False, otherwise True. It is exactly same as A V B V C